# Can I use more than one Theft card

Tags: saboteur-2

Can I use more than one Theft card in Saboteur 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't, because

> no player can have 2 action cards of the same type affecting them at the same time.

This is part of the passage that introduces cards like Theft, so while you're technically not "affected" by a *Theft* in front of you, it would seem that a loose interpretation is in order.

*Hands Off* uses wording that implies a player could have multiple *Theft* cards ("remove one Theft card from in front of any player"), but that's probably just more imprecise wording.

---

The following are the other restrictions on on playing actions:

- You cannot break a player's tool when that player's tool is already broken.
- You cannot fix a tool that's not broken.
- You cannot play a *Theft* card while trapped.

Based on the above, it's conceivable one might be forbidden from taking following useless actions, but they aren't actually forbidden by the rules:

- Playing a *Hands Off* card on someone who doesn't have a Theft card.
- Playing a *Free At Last* card on someone who isn't trapped.
- Playing a *Trapped* card on someone who is trapped.

Comment: Deleted unconstructive comment thread.

Answer (score 1):

No. 
Unless the previous *Theft* card is removed by a *Hands off* -card.

[The Z-Man games rules for Saboteur 2](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Saboteur_2.pdf) states

> As in the base game, in this expansion **no player can have 2 action
>   cards of the same type**  affecting them at the same time.

(Same rule can be found also in the [Nordic edition](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/215465/nordic-compilation-edition-2012) rulebook)